# IF EXISTS it should UPDATE the row, ELSE INSERT INTO a new row. How to solve this error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**How to solve this ERROR?**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update user_options set value='1' where name='slider';INSERT INTO user_options (' at line 2

**Code**

```
public function update($slider, $welcomebox, $servicebox, $postbox, $testimonials, $welcomemessage, $welcomededcription, $welcomelink, $welcomelinktitle, $servicetitle, $totalservicedisplay, $ourservice, $blogtitle, $totalblogdisplay, $ourblog, $newstitle, $totalnewsdisplay, $ournews, $totaltestimonialdisplay, $ourtestimonial) {
    $db = connectionstart();
    $currentdatetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

    $sql = "select * from user_options ";
    $result = mysql_evaluate($db, $sql, 0);

    $columns = array(
        array(
            'name' => 'slider'
            , 'value' => $slider
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'welcomebox'
            , 'value' => $welcomebox
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'servicebox'
            , 'value' => $servicebox
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'postbox'
            , 'value' => $postbox
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'testimonials'
            , 'value' => $testimonials
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'welcomemessage'
            , 'value' => $welcomemessage
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'welcomededcription'
            , 'value' => $welcomededcription
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'welcomelink'
            , 'value' => $welcomelink
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'welcomelinktitle'
            , 'value' => $welcomelinktitle
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'servicetitle'
            , 'value' => $servicetitle
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'totalservicedisplay'
            , 'value' => $totalservicedisplay
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'ourservice'
            , 'value' => $ourservice
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'blogtitle'
            , 'value' => $blogtitle
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'totalblogdisplay'
            , 'value' => $totalblogdisplay
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'ourblog'
            , 'value' => $ourblog
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'newstitle'
            , 'value' => $newstitle
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'totalnewsdisplay'
            , 'value' => $totalnewsdisplay
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'ournews'
            , 'value' => $ournews
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'totaltestimonialdisplay'
            , 'value' => $totaltestimonialdisplay
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'ourtestimonial'
            , 'value' => $ourtestimonial
            , 'entrydate' => $currentdatetime
        )
    );




            $results = mysql_updateoptionfields($db, $columns);
            if ($results == true) {
                $results = 'SUCCESS';
            }


    connectionclose($db);
    return $result;
}
```

**Function mysql_updateoptionfields**

```
function mysql_updateoptionfields($db, $columns) {
    $sql = "";
    foreach ($columns as $obj) {
        $sql.="INSERT INTO user_options (name,value,entrydate) VALUES ('{$obj['name']}','{$obj['value']}','{$obj['entrydate']}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=values(name);
                update user_options set value='{$obj['value']}' where name='{$obj['name']}';";
    }
    if ($sql != '') {
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $db) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I want to insert data if exixts otherwise update based on name

Comment: your syntax is not correct. By the way, is there any unique index on "name" field?

Comment: yes name field is unique @SubrataDeyPappu and then tell me right syntax

Comment: Here's the query skeleton:
`INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (field1, field2, YOUR_UNIQUE_FIELD,...,filedN)
VALUES (val1,val2,......,valN)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE val1 = VALUES(field1),val2 = VALUES(field2),...,valN = VALUES(fieldN);`

Comment: If a duplicate key found then you are not supposed to update that unique field. Because it's already in that row so that it raises an alert that duplicate key found. In this case you need to update the other fields of that particular unique field.

Comment: look like same as above what is difference your and mine plz correct mine syntax in my code plz i m student and i m in exam plz help me dude @SubrataDeyPappu

Comment: i dnt wnt to update name i want to update only vale @SubrataDeyPappu

Comment: `INSERT INTO 
user_options (name,value,entrydate) 
VALUES ('{$obj['name']}','{$obj['value']}','{$obj['entrydate']}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value),entrydate = VALUES(entrydate);` Try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102315/discussion-between-kevin-patel-and-subrata-dey-pappu).

Comment: same error @SubrataDeyPappu

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO subs
  (col1,col2,col3)
VALUES
  (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  Col1     = VALUES(value1),
  Col2     = VALUES(value2);
```

As per your question

```
INSERT INTO values
  (name,value,entrydate)
VALUES
('{$obj['name']}','{$obj['value']}','{$obj['entrydate']}')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  value     = VALUES(value),
  entrydate     = VALUES(entrydate)
```

Comment: plz update in my code i m student and i m in exam plz help me correct my code @User

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 problems in your code:

1. You should not use mysql_*() functions any longer, they are deprecated and removed from php7.
2. mysql_query() cannot execute more than 1 sql statements in a call. This is the reason for your syntax error message. Remove the separate update statement.
3. In the `on duplicate key update` part of the sql statement you should assign value to the value field, not to the name field.

   `... value='{$obj['value']}'`

Comment: please correct my code i m student and i m in exam plz help me update my code with ur suggection @Shadow

Comment: See the updated aswer for a hint on the code. I'm not going to give you a copy-paste solution.

Comment: please give me copy paste solution m in exam dude plz help me  @Shadow

Comment: I gave you the relevant part of the code that you need to change. I described the issues with your code. Put these together.

Comment: areeee dude i m student of bscit in 5 sem i dnt knw anything plz help me give me copy paste solution @Shadow

Answer (score 1):

"INSERT … ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE” use this. It will help you to fix ur problem.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html